# How to avoid duplicate records while retrieving using Inner Join in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, stored-procedures, inner-join

Here is my Store Procedure for printing purpose. I am facing issue as i get records twice as they exist due to commented join. I want to get output as mentioned below in question. I am a novice to DB. Help in this regard will be appreciated.

```
DECLARE @path AS VARCHAR(100)
SET @path = N'~/BillAttachments/166/'
DECLARE @billID AS INT
SET @billID = 166

SELECT bh.billID,bh.statusID,bh.modifiedOn,bs.statusName
FROM dbo.eInvoice_tbl_billHistory AS bh
--INNER JOIN dbo.eInvoice_tbl_billAttachment AS ba ON bh.billID = ba.billID
--INNER JOIN dbo.eInvoice_tbl_billAttachment AS ba ON ba.billID = bh.billID
INNER JOIN dbo.eInvoice_tbl_billStatus AS bs ON bh.statusID = bs.statusID
WHERE bh.billID=@billID;
```

when i try to fetch these columns from the required tables

```
ba.attachmentID ,
        @path + ba.fileName AS asad ,
        ba.attachmentDescription ,
        ba.billAttachmentStatus,
```

Output is:

```
166 3   2015-11-30 11:44:18.663 Approve
166 3   2015-11-30 11:44:18.663 Approve
166 5   2015-11-30 11:44:42.600 Paid
166 5   2015-11-30 11:44:42.600 Paid
```

but desired output is:

```
166 3   2015-11-30 11:44:18.663 Approve
166 5   2015-11-30 11:44:42.600 Paid
```

Comment: You should investigate the data to figure out why you are getting the duplicates.  Although you can fix the problem by modifying the query (say, by using `select distinct`), you should ensure that the data is correct and doesn't contain duplicates.

Comment: Kindly review the question again, it has been modified

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [`DISTINCT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176104.aspx):

> Specifies that only unique rows can appear in the result set

```
SELECT DISTINCT bh.billID,bh.statusID,bh.modifiedOn,bs.statusName 
FROM dbo.eInvoice_tbl_billHistory AS bh
--INNER JOIN dbo.eInvoice_tbl_billAttachment AS ba ON bh.billID = ba.billID
--INNER JOIN dbo.eInvoice_tbl_billAttachment AS ba ON ba.billID = bh.billID
INNER JOIN dbo.eInvoice_tbl_billStatus AS bs ON bh.statusID = bs.statusID
WHERE bh.billID=@billID;
```

Other method is to use `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT bh.billID,bh.statusID,bh.modifiedOn,bs.statusName 
FROM dbo.eInvoice_tbl_billHistory AS bh
--INNER JOIN dbo.eInvoice_tbl_billAttachment AS ba ON bh.billID = ba.billID
--INNER JOIN dbo.eInvoice_tbl_billAttachment AS ba ON ba.billID = bh.billID
INNER JOIN dbo.eInvoice_tbl_billStatus AS bs ON bh.statusID = bs.statusID
WHERE bh.billID=@billID
GROUP BY bh.billID,bh.statusID,bh.modifiedOn,bs.statusName;
```

Comment: You can also do SELECT ... UNION same SELECT to get distinct values.

Answer (score 4):

A different approach if your rule is getting more complex which row you want to keep using a CTE and the [`ROW_NUMBER`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) ranking function:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT bh.billID, 
           bh.statusID, 
           bh.modifiedOn, 
           bs.statusName,
           rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER() (PARTITION BY bh.billID, bh.statusID ORDER BY bh.modifiedOn ASC)
    FROM   dbo.eInvoice_tbl_billHistory AS bh 
           INNER JOIN dbo.eInvoice_tbl_billStatus AS bs 
                   ON bh.statusID = bs.statusID 
    WHERE  bh.billID = @billID; 
)
SELECT billID, statusID, modifiedOn, statusName
FROM CTE 
WHERE RN = 1
```

In this example i keep the first row of each `BillId`+`StatusID` combination according to the `modifiedOn` datetime.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you are joining with eInvoice_tbl_billAttachment AS ba, but not using it in the select statement. You mention that this seems to be cause the duplicate rows, so I guess there are 2 rows in this table with billID = 166.

Why are you joining on this table then? If it you just want to return rows from eInvoice_tbl_billHistory AS bh which also have at least one row in ba, you could use an exists statement instead:

```
DECLARE @path AS VARCHAR(100)
SET @path = N'~/BillAttachments/166/'
DECLARE @billID AS INT
SET @billID = 166

SELECT bh.billID,bh.statusID,bh.modifiedOn,bs.statusName
FROM dbo.eInvoice_tbl_billHistory AS bh
INNER JOIN dbo.eInvoice_tbl_billStatus AS bs ON bh.statusID = bs.statusID
WHERE bh.billID=@billID 
AND exists (select 1 from dbo.eInvoice_tbl_billAttachment AS ba 
            where  bh.billID = ba.billID);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Distinct Keyword after select keyword.